# Weird output from a jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have to update a text with the price which is coming from Smarty and put into a data-attribute, to display my price here,i'm using this simple command,however it shows "object Object" instead of the actual price,any idea?

```
$('.bundle-product-price').text($("[data-vitals-price]"));
```

Comment: try $('.bundle-product-price').text($("[data-vitals-price]").val());

Comment: @BhumiShah ,it shows me on now,wtf ..

Comment: @KiranShahi what for ,it's a span i need to update.

Comment: What you want to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output shows `[object Object]` as you're providing a jQuery object to the `text()` function. If you want to provide the actual `data-vitals-price` value as the `text()`, then you need to provide that value instead.

Assuming there' is only ever one element with that `data` attribute, this should work:

```
$('.bundle-product-price').text($("[data-vitals-price]").data('vitals-price'));
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I think your second jquery selection will need .val after it, in order to get the actual value of it. It sounds like it is trying to put the actual object in as text instead of the value/text of the object eg

```
$('.bundle-product-price').text($("[data-vitals-price]").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("[data-vitals-price]")` - it selects the DOM element that has the attribute, not the value of the attribute. Try the following code (it looks like your data attribute is in the same DOM element you try to update):

```
$('.bundle-product-price').text($('.bundle-product-price').attr('data-vitals-price'));
```

or

```
    $('.bundle-product-price').text($('.bundle-product-price').data('vitals-price'));
```